# Merge [.iso] with [iso-image]

Tags: support, status-declined, tag-synonym-request

[Option to mount .iso in Windows 8 missing](https://superuser.com/q/497429/86550) post had tag with [.iso](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.iso) while we have already [iso-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iso-image) tag for the ISO file.

While it's the only question which is tagged with that tag but I think it's worth to create a synonym

Comment: did you mean create a synonym? There's nothing to merge here.

Comment: @Sathya my apologies, Yes I mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't see a need to create a synonym - especially when it's used just once. Maybe we can revisit this at a later point